# Intelligent way of rewriting a Matlab function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I've been recently converting Matlab code to C++ due to Matlab not being able to handle my desired problem size.  However, I've run into a problem regarding Matlab's `colon operator`.

I have an array ue that is size `nx+2*m`, where `m` and `nx` are integers. `u` is of size`nx`.  For what I need to do, I have to modify the `ue` array as follows

```
ue = zeros(nx+2*m,1)
u = zeros(nx,1)
ue((m+1):(nx+m)) = u(1:nx)
```

Sorry if this is a trivial question, however I am a novice at C++ and would like to hear opinions on how to efficiently do this.

EDIT:  For those people who do not know Matlab.  The colon operator acts as a for loop.

Comment: What about that can Matlab not handle?

Comment: I am doing large scale CFD calculations (solving 3D compressible Euler equations with high order accurate numerics.)  Hence, my need for a language like C++.  I would like to stay away from Fortran as the people around me use C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MATLAB code, literally translated to C++, is:

```
std::vector<double> ue(nx+2*m, 0);
std::vector<double> u(nx, 0);
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < nx; ++ii) {
   ue[m + ii] = u[ii];
}
```

You can use `std::copy` to replace the loop for something more readable:

```
std::copy(u.begin(), u.end(), ue.begin()+m);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, would it not be ue[2*m + ii] = u[ii];?

Comment: @Simon: no, your MATLAB code indexes from `m+1` to `m+nx`. Here I index from `m` to `m+nx-1` (C++ uses 0-based indexing, MATLAB uses 1-based indexing).

Answer (score 0):

If you can define where you want your loop to start and end it'll be a trivial fix.  If you can't define it (ie its a lambda function) then don't use a for loop but use a proper lambda (assuming you have C++ 14+)

Also, if (m+1) is of a type (N+m) you could look into BOOST_FOREACH for more readable code.

Comment: I can define where my array starts and ends, but to me it is not trivial, pardon my C++ ignorance.  My initial thought is to do it in 2 for loops, where I have a tmp array.  First: loop from m+1 to nx + m and have Tmp[i] = ue[i].  Then have a second loop that goes from 1 to nx and have u[i] = Tmp[i].  I don't claim this is a good way.

Comment: Why do you need 2 loops?